# How to make a Docker container available to a task in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, docker, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I want to run my integration tests against a local Docker-hosted SQL Server 2019 database inside an Azure pipeline.  I'm trying to copy over `sqlpackage` to this Docker image so I can restore a `.bacpac` each time in order to setup the database before the tests.  Here's the YAML config I have so far:

**azure-pipelines.yml**:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: 'sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests'
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU5-ubuntu-16.04'
    ports:
    - 1433:1433/tcp
    env:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'P@ssW0rd!'

trigger:
- azure-pipelines

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Echo some Docker info from bash'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'docker info'
      docker info
      echo 'docker ps'
      docker ps

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Copy sqlpackage to Docker SQL Server'
  inputs:
    command: 'cp'
    arguments: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/DBProject/_TestDb_/sqlpackage-linux/sqlpackage sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests:/tmp/sqlpackage'
```

I want to access the Docker container `sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests` from my `Docker@2` step so I can copy the sqlpackage binary into it - the database `.bacpac` will later be copied, and sqlpackage will be run to restore the DB from it - but I get the error "Error: No such container:path: sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests:/tmp".  So it looks like either the Docker container isn't being started or it's not being made available to my task.  In addition, `docker ps` in the first task shows no output.

So how can I make the Docker container available for my tasks to copy files to and execute commands on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem.

First, I needed to declare that the job was dependent on the service for the container to be started (`docker ps` now lists it), by adding the following before the `variables:` section:

```
services:
  sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests: sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests
```

... but it still got a name assigned with some random characters tacked onto the end, preventing me from directly addressing it with the docker command.  I noticed that an environment variable was created, however, containing JSON that mapped the container name to its ID:

```
AGENT_CONTAINERMAPPING = {
  "sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests": {
    "id": "623aa2b3a1505da472d051e7845bfd5f20c979f0ff94fca63fb115e2d942e8b3"
  }
}
```

So I first used a PowerShell task to pull that ID out and export it to a variable:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: varsCalc
  displayName: 'Calculate variables in Powershell'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $extractedId = Echo '$(Agent.ContainerMapping)' | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -Expand sqlserver_linux_container_for_integration_tests | Select -Expand id
      Echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqlServerTestDbId;isOutput=true]$extractedId"
```

I was then able to use that variable in Docker tasks where I needed the container ID, such as copying to `[containerId]:/local/container/path`:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'TestDb - copy sqlpackage to SQLServer container'
  inputs:
    command: 'cp'
    arguments: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/DBProject/_TestDb_/sqlpackage-linux.tgz $(varsCalc.sqlServerTestDbId):/tmp/sqlpackage-linux.tgz'
```

Comment: Great ! You could accept your answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.